# I want to operate firefox elements through selenium_js in centos environment. How should I configure the environment?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I want to operate firefox elements through selenium_js in centos environment. How should I configure the environment?

**i want to configure headerless & geckodriver**

```js
const { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');


const screen = {
  width: 640,
  height: 480
};

const options = new firefox.Options().addArguments('-headless');

async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.FIREFOX).setFirefoxOptions(options).build();
  try {
    await driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr");
    await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver", Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs("webdriver - Google Search"), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
};

example()
```

i expect that work.

it will work by python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')

bro=driver.get('https://www.google.cn/')
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```